# Xs and Os: XOXXOO = 387

Tags: pattern

XOXXOO = 387, OOOXXX = 450, OXOX = 204, XXOOXX = (???)
In this problem of puzzle certain values for X and O create the number given.
The form of logic is XOXXOO makes 387 as OOOXXX makes 450 etc

Comment: This is one of the questions from the iq test at this link: https://bakaiq.com/iq-tests/sendto/X10Test/ On that page it states "No discussing test items with others or posting your solutions elsewhere".

Answer (score 2):

This puzzle is quite loosely defined, so that many answers must be possible, but here is one:

> 336

The logic

> Take the number of O's that are predated by a X. Add 40. Add 10 if the code starts with an O. Multiply by the number of O's. Multiply by the number of X's.

Vérification:

> 387 = (3+40)*3*3
>  450 = (0+40+10)*3*3
>  204 = (1+40+10)*2*2

And then

> 336 = (2+40)*2*4